# Where and join in LINQ is not working

Tags: c#, linq, join, where-clause

I have the following function:

```
public IList<Movie> GetMovieTimeTable(DateTime date)
{
   var result = (from m in movierepo.Movies
   join t in timetablerepo.TimeTables on m.MovieId equals t.MovieId
   where t.StartTime.Date == date.Date
   select m).Distinct().ToList();
   return result;
}
```

It works fine, but the where condition doesn't work. Still all records from timetablerepo with the same MovieId are returned. 
What's the reason for that? What I am doing wrong? And what is the correct way to do this?

**EDIT: Example:**

I have an record in Movies with MovieId = 34 In TimeTable there are 3 records:

```
MovieId StartTime 
34 08-06-2015 19:00 
34 09-06-2015 21:00 
34 10-06-2015 20:00 
(Dutch DateTime Format)
```

Given the date in 'date' I want to filter the records to that day. (Time is important at this moment). Now I'am getting al these records.

**Example 2:**

DateTime
    Date = {8-6-2015 00:00:00}

```
Result.Count=6 (That's right)
[0] 
MovieId = 2
(Etc..)
   TimeTables
   [0]
   MovieId = 2
   StartTime = {5-5-2015 20:00:00}
   (Etc..)
   [1]
   MovieId =2 
   StartTime = {28-5-2015 20:00:00}
   (Etc..)
[1]
MovieId = 13
TimeTables
   [0]
   MovieId = 13
   StartTime = {28-5-2015 21:00:00}
   (etc..)
   [1]
   MovieId = 13
   StartTime = {28-5-2015 19:50:00}
   (etc..)
(etc..)
```

**Edit 3:**
Movie model:

```
public partial class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        TimeTables = new HashSet<TimeTable>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public int MovieGenre { get; set; }
    public string MoviePicture { get; set; }
    public string MovieDescription { get; set; }
    public string MovieShortText { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieIs3d { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieIsImax { get; set; }
    public int MovieLanguage { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieSubtitled { get; set; }
    public int? MovieMinimalAge { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieHasDrugs { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieHasViolence { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieHasSex { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieHasSwearing { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieIsScary { get; set; }
    public bool? MovieHasDiscrimination { get; set; }
    public string MovieTrailer { get; set; }
    public int MovieLength { get; set; }
    public int? Genre_GenreId { get; set; }
    public int? Language_LanguageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TimeTable> TimeTables { get; set; }
}
```

TimeTable:

```
public partial class TimeTable
{
    public TimeTable()
    {
        Reservations = new HashSet<Reservation>();
    }
    public int TimeTableId { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public int SeatsAvaible { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit 4:**
A query on TimeTable to Movie is also possible but then I get multiple movie records because there are more than 1 records in Timetable for each movie, and I'm not so good in query's, but if you have the Solution I would luke to hear :)

Comment: try t.StartTime.Date == date

Comment: Can you include some sample rows of data, including some examples that you are thinking shouldn't be returned?  And what date it was run for...

Comment: date is already a DateTime object

Comment: This only returns `Movie` objects, so I'm confused by what "Still all records from timetablerepo with the same MovideId are returned" means.

Comment: @AlwaysAProgrammer That would result in no matches if the `date` does not have a time of midnight.  If it does then `date.Date` and `date` will be the same.

Comment: A trick for evaluating what query Linq created is to remove the distinct().tolist(), and place a breakpoint on the return result.  At that point, you can right-click on the result object and view the actual query.  This should help direct you in the future as to what went wrong.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  You are retrieving all the movies that are showing on the date specified in `date`.  What did you want?  Based on the name GetMovieTimeTable, I would expect that you would give it a movie id and a date and it would return a list of all the start times for that movie.  But you aren't giving it a movie id.  Nor is it returning a times.

Comment: I want to get the movies with (a) record(s) in TimeTable matching the day in 'date'. TimeTable has a row MovieId, what I use for the Join statement. The query works fine, but I get all records from timetable, as also the records where the date does not match

Comment: So you are saying to you are getting a movie that doesn't have a record in TimeTable that starts on `date`?

Comment: No, all Movies have one or more records in TimeTable with different datetimes. And all the rows from TimeTable are returned.

Comment: Try fluent syntax, is the result still same:
== START ==

var result = movierepo.Movies.Join(timetablerepo.TimeTables,
      m => m.MovieId,
      t => r.t.MovieId,
      (movie,time) => { 
                       if(time.StartTime.Date == date.Date)
                         return m;
                       else 
                         return null;
                      }
    ).Where(m=>m!=null).Distinct.ToList();

== END ==

Comment: I am just trying to provide a suggestion, I am not able to get your question clearly, could you explain with an example, what is data, what should be the result and what are you getting, just few rows would be suffice

Comment: Example: I have an record in Movies with MovieId = 34
In TimeTable there are 3 records:
MovieId  StartTime
34          08-06-2015 19:00
34          09-06-2015  21:00
34          10-06-2015  20:00
(Dutch DateTime Format)

With the date in 'date' I want to filter the records to a specific date.

Comment: If you have that data, then movie with movieid `34` should only be returned when you pass in a date of `08-06-2015`, `09-06-2015`, or `10-06-2015`.

Comment: Please also include some example output that you are getting...  And explain why it is wrong.  It's hard to understand exactly what output you're trying to get from the limited explanation.

Comment: Ok, lastly, can you show what the generated SQL looks like?  Rogala identified the process for doing that, in an earlier comment.

Comment: I think I see the problem.  He's wants a filtered list of TimeTable records, but asking for the Movies that have an entry where any TimeTable matches.  When he then asks for the related TimeTable entries for that movie, it returns all the timetable records, likely from a lazy evaluation.

Comment: Will need your definition of Movie, I suspect it has a virtual property that's getting filled when you request it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, added movie and timetable models

Comment: An solution to get the movie's via the TimeTable is also a option but then I get multiple movie records because 1 movie have more than 1 records in Timetable and I don't now how to filter/group that.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I believe the problem is because you are trying to reuse the data classes to hold your View data.  It would be easiest to just create a new set of classes, but this might get you by:

```
public IList<Movie> GetMovieTimeTable(DateTime date)
{
   var result = movierepo.Movies
     .Join(timetablerepo.TimeTables,m=>m.MovieId,tt=>tt.MovieId,
       (m,g)=>new Movie{
         MovieId=m.MovieId,
         ... rest of properties here ...
         TimeTables=g.Where(tt=>tt.StartDate.Date==date.Date).ToList()
       })
     .Where(m=>m.TimeTables.Any())
     .ToList();
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Second solution doesn't have the date comparison

Comment: Updated answer to reflect forcing the TimeTable property to get pre-filled with just the records you want.  Depending on how that property is defined, this may not work and force you to create a ViewModel for the Movies that has an `IEnumerable<TimeTable> TimeTables {get;set;}` property.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `TimeTables = g.Where(tt => tt.StartDate.Date == date.Date).ToList()`.  Updated answer.

Comment: After a few searches on SO I found something like <IENummerable> not implemented in Movie OR Timetable. Do you have an idea?  The models are pasted in the original question.